Mac Pro M1 Sonoma not recognising Ubuntu Bootable USB
I have not huge experience with computers, drives or coding but I require to have Linux on my MacPro M1 Sonoma. I have install UBUNTU into a SSD that I have checked that works on a Windows Laptop, but I cannot get it recognised by the Mac at the booting menu. I have already tried different UBUNTU versions and I do not know what else to try? Any advice or guidance?

You have to install Asahi Linux/Ubuntu Asahi from within MacOS. Checkout the link in the other comment.
